# Fixing a basic word count in python

Tags: python, string, count, word-count

So I have problems with my code, my word count always equals "4" which is not accurate whenever I type in different amounts of words.

This is my code:

```
word=raw_input("Enter your string please: ")
count=0
for i in "word":
    count += 1
    if word == " ":
        print(count) 
print "Your word count:", count
print "Your character count:", (len(word))
```

Sample output:

```
Enter your string please: ched hcdbe checbj
Your word count: 4
Your character count: 17
```

My character count works perfectly fine, it's just my word count. I'm confused as to what I need to fix. Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `for i in "word"`? You're iterating over the string `'word'`, which has 4 characters.. Refer to the variable, `word`

Comment: OH so i take out the quotes?

Comment: but then it tells me I have 17 words when I only have 3 then :(

Comment: Yes, that's right. Note that you are not counting words however. You have to split the string for that. So rather something like `len(word.split())`

Comment: so how would I incorporate it?

Comment: If you want to change your algorithm you can move the count increment into the if statement, then move the print statement outside of the for loop completely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are iterating over "word" as a string, which contains 4 characters.

There is another problem with counting your words, the output of count words and count characters will be the same.

Here is a shorter fixed code:

```
word=raw_input("Enter your string please: ")
print ("Your word count:", len(word.split()))
print ("Your character count:", len(word))
```

output:

```
Enter your string please: This is a Test
Your word count: 4
Your character count: 14
```

Answer (score 2):

**Debugging**:

The following line is invalid since you are iterating over each element in the string word not the user-input:

```
for i in "word":
```

**Should have been**:

```
for i in word:
```

**Complete Fix** (Using two separate variables for word and char counting):

```
word= input("Enter your string please: ")
charCount = 0
wordCount = 0
for i in word:
    charCount += 1
    if i == ' ':
        wordCount += 2
print("Your character count:", charCount)
print("Your word count:", wordCount)
```

**Now, a shorter way**:

Using `str.format()` and `len()`:

```
word = input("Enter your string please: ")

print("Total words: {}".format(len(word.split())))
print("Total Characters: {}".format(len(word)))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
Enter your string please: hey, how're you?
Total words: 3
Total Characters: 16
```

Answer (score 1):

"word" is iterable string object, you are iterating through each symbol of the string "word", try to change "word" for word.split() and get count by len() method:

```
word = input("Enter your string please: ")
print("Your word count:", len(word.split()))
print("Your character count:", len(word))
```

Answer (score 1):

your statement for the for loop was iterating through the string "word" and not the variable word which you saved as input.
also, your if statement was for word, instead of iterator.

```
word=input("Enter your string please: ")
new_word = word.lstrip(" ").rstrip(" ")
new_word += ' '
count=0
for i in new_word:
    if i == " ":
        count += 1
print(count) 
print("Your word count: ", count)
print("Your character count: ", (len(new_word.rstrip(' '))))
print("Your character count: ", (len(word)))
```

Comment: You've complicated the logic by appending an extra space on the end, which you then strip away to print its length. It also ensures that the count would always be at least 1, even if the string was empty and the character count 0.

Answer (score 0):

Youre actually iterating through the word "word"

if you want to get a list of words you should use the `split` keyword instead.

```
>>> words = 'this is a test sentence'
>>> word_list = words.split()
>>> print(len(word_list))
5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
inp = raw_input("Enter your string: ")

word_count = len(inp.split())
chr_count = len(inp)

print(word_count, chr_count)
```

Example:

```
>>> Enter your string: foo bar
>>> 2 7
```

Answer (score 0):

You're iterating through each letter of "word" which will result in a length of 4.  You want to split your input string on space after trimming off then get the length of the resulting list.

```
word=raw_input("Enter your string please: ")
print("Your word count: %s", len(word.strip().split(" ")))
print("Your character count: %s", (len(word)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also get some value out of the Counter in collections.

```
from collections import Counter

my_string = "xxx yyy xxx"
c = Counter(my_string.split(' '))

print("number of words:", len(my_string.split(' ')))
print("number of characters:", len(my_string))
print("number of unique words:",len(c))
print("most common word:" , c.most_common()[0][0])
print("least common word:", c.most_common()[-1][0])
```

Gives:

```
number of words 3
number of characters 11
number of unique words: 2
most common word: xxx
least common word: yyy
```